# Перемножение матрицы вероятностей, неверные значения на большом количестве итераций

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Следующий код перемножает *матрицу вероятностей `p`* саму на себя определенное количество раз. На первых 50 итерациях все нормально, сумма вероятностей в каждой строке `sum == 1`, но потом я получаю `sum > 1`, и примерно после 70-й итерации я получаю `infinity`. Не понимаю, почему.

Сумма вероятностей в каждой строке должна быть равна `1`. Это классическая модель *цепи Маркова*. И независимо от количества перемножений должно получаться `sum == 1` в каждой строке. Полагаю, что проблема в вычислениях с плавающей точкой.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int trials = 80;
    double[][] p = {
            {0.02, 0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.92, 0.02},
            {0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.47, 0.02, 0.47, 0.02, 0.02}};

    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
        p = matrixMultiplication(5, 5, 5, p, p);

        if (t % 15 == 0) {
            System.out.println("t=" + t);
            for (double[] row : p) {
                for (double el : row)
                    System.out.printf("%9.4f ", el);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static double[][] matrixMultiplication(
        int m, int n, int p, double[][] a, double[][] b) {

    double[][] result = new double[m][p];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];

    return result;
}

/*
t=0
   0,0470    0,0380    0,3602    0,3692    0,1856
   0,4520    0,0380    0,1172    0,3692    0,0236
   0,8570    0,0380    0,0362    0,0452    0,0236
   0,0470    0,8480    0,0362    0,0452    0,0236
   0,0470    0,4430    0,0362    0,4502    0,0236
t=15
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
t=30
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
   0,2730    0,2657    0,1462    0,2472    0,0678
t=45
   0,2734    0,2661    0,1464    0,2475    0,0679
   0,2734    0,2661    0,1464    0,2475    0,0679
   0,2734    0,2661    0,1464    0,2475    0,0679
   0,2734    0,2661    0,1464    0,2475    0,0679
   0,2734    0,2661    0,1464    0,2475    0,0679
t=60
178185634959455072,0000 173419563798949152,0000 95404141521724560,0000 161347262672613632,0000 44268013819250744,0000
178185634959455072,0000 173419563798949152,0000 95404141521724560,0000 161347262672613632,0000 44268013819250744,0000
178185634959455072,0000 173419563798949152,0000 95404141521724560,0000 161347262672613632,0000 44268013819250744,0000
178185634959455072,0000 173419563798949152,0000 95404141521724560,0000 161347262672613632,0000 44268013819250744,0000
178185634959455072,0000 173419563798949152,0000 95404141521724560,0000 161347262672613632,0000 44268013819250744,0000
t=75
 Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity
 Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity
 Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity
 Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity
 Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity  Infinity
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вычисления с плавающей точкой, особенно с большими дробными частями, в большинстве случаев связаны с округлением. Вопрос в том, *как* и *что* округлять?

#### Умножение матриц с плавающей точкой

Для перемножения матриц можно использовать [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) вместо `double`. В данном случае 34-значного формата [`DECIMAL128`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL128) может быть достаточно для первых 151 тестов. Результат можно представить в виде *научной записи*, если требуется экспонента.

Для преобразования `double` в `BigDecimal` используйте метод [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)) и не используйте конструктор [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)), иначе вы можете получить *непредсказуемый* аппендикс к каждому числу. Наверное, это основная ошибка при расчетах с `double`.

В этом случае, начиная с 5-го теста, суммы строк становятся меньше `1` из-за округления, затем они становятся еще меньше, и после 151-го теста вы получите исключение [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) *underflow*, потому что числа становятся меньше границ округления.

#### Сферический конь в вакууме

Для *более точных* вычислений можно использовать [`UNLIMITED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#UNLIMITED) - *неограниченную точность арифметики*. В таком случае суммы строк *стабильно равны `1`* на каждой итерации, но оно думает *очень долго*, даже в *многопоточном* режиме [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#parallel--), поэтому я остановился на 20-м тесте с таким *математическим контекстом* `MathContext`. На вычисление 20-й итерации уходит около *пяти минут*, для меня этого достаточно. Время для расчета последующих тестов растет в *геометрической прогрессии* с приблизительным значением *знаменателя* `3`, но оно продолжает работать без утечек памяти. Надеюсь, что это так, поэтому думаю, что для расчета первых 30 тестов может потребоваться примерно более *года*...

#### Рабочий код

Первые 151 тестов в 34-значном формате `DECIMAL128`, каждый пятнадцатый тест выводится с использованием *научной записи*. Можно преобразовать эти значения в `doubleValue` и округлить суммы строк обратно до `1` до 65-го теста, но в таком случае вы получите `0.0` после 128-го теста.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 5; // измерения
    int trials = 151;

    // правила для математических операций
    MathContext mc = MathContext.DECIMAL128;

    BigDecimal[][] p = toBigDecimal(new double[][]{
            {0.02, 0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.92, 0.02},
            {0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.47, 0.02, 0.47, 0.02, 0.02}});

    // умножение матриц
    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        p = parallelMatrixMultiplication(mc, d, d, d, p, p);
        // вывод каждого пятнадцатого теста
        if (t % 15 == 0) outputMatrix(p, t, time);
    }
}
```

```java
static void outputMatrix(BigDecimal[][] matrix, int t, long time) {
    System.out.println("Тест: " + t);
    for (BigDecimal[] row : matrix) {
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        for (BigDecimal element : row) {
            sum = sum.add(element);
            // строковое представление текущего
            // элемента с использованием научной
            // записи, если требуется экспонента
            System.out.print(element.toString() + " ");
        }
        // сумма строки в том же формате
        System.out.println("|| " + sum.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Время: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}
```

```java
static BigDecimal[][] toBigDecimal(double[][] matrix) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix)
            .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                    .mapToObj(BigDecimal::valueOf)
                    .toArray(BigDecimal[]::new))
            .toArray(BigDecimal[][]::new);
}
```

```java
/**
 * Параллельное умножение матриц, многопоточный режим
 *
 * @param mc правила для математических операций
 * @param m  строки матрицы 'a'
 * @param n  колонки матрицы 'a'
 *           и строки матрицы 'b'
 * @param p  колонки матрицы 'b'
 * @param a  первая матрица 'm×n'
 * @param b  вторая матрица 'n×p'
 * @return результирующая матрица 'm×p'
 */
static BigDecimal[][] parallelMatrixMultiplication(
        MathContext mc, int m, int n, int p,
        BigDecimal[][] a, BigDecimal[][] b) {
    return IntStream.range(0, m)
            .parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, p)
                    .mapToObj(j -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                            .mapToObj(k -> a[i][k].multiply(b[k][j], mc))
                            .reduce((bd1, bd2) -> bd1.add(bd2, mc))
                            .orElse(new BigDecimal("0")))
                    .toArray(BigDecimal[]::new))
            .toArray(BigDecimal[][]::new);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Тест: 0
0.0470 0.0380 0.3602 0.3692 0.1856 || 1.0000
0.4520 0.0380 0.1172 0.3692 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.8570 0.0380 0.0362 0.0452 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.0470 0.8480 0.0362 0.0452 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.0470 0.4430 0.0362 0.4502 0.0236 || 1.0000
Время: 40
Тест: 15
0.2730292887828770329701825732219358 0.2657263599045893296731643158997408 0.1461853247179238943858654633117832 0.2472282818117836636296180707045103 0.06783074478282607934116957686195174 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999992184
0.2730292887828770329701825732219358 0.2657263599045893296731643158997408 0.1461853247179238943858654633117832 0.2472282818117836636296180707045103 0.06783074478282607934116957686195174 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999992184
0.2730292887828770329701825732219358 0.2657263599045893296731643158997408 0.1461853247179238943858654633117832 0.2472282818117836636296180707045103 0.06783074478282607934116957686195174 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999992184
0.2730292887828770329701825732219356 0.2657263599045893296731643158997406 0.1461853247179238943858654633117831 0.2472282818117836636296180707045100 0.06783074478282607934116957686195169 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999992099
0.2730292887828770329701825732219358 0.2657263599045893296731643158997408 0.1461853247179238943858654633117832 0.2472282818117836636296180707045103 0.06783074478282607934116957686195174 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999992184
Время: 5
Тест: 30
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200011 0.2657263599045893296731643152165811 0.1461853247179238943858654629359533 0.2472282818117836636296180700689076 0.06783074478282607934116957668756474 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900784
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
Время: 4
Тест: 45
0.2730292887828770329701595715303174 0.2657263599045893296731419294524381 0.1461853247179238943858531477474961 0.2472282818117836636295972426507773 0.06783074478282607934116386237659124 || 0.99999999999999999999991575375762014
0.2730292887828770329701595715303174 0.2657263599045893296731419294524381 0.1461853247179238943858531477474961 0.2472282818117836636295972426507773 0.06783074478282607934116386237659124 || 0.99999999999999999999991575375762014
0.2730292887828770329701595715303174 0.2657263599045893296731419294524381 0.1461853247179238943858531477474961 0.2472282818117836636295972426507773 0.06783074478282607934116386237659124 || 0.99999999999999999999991575375762014
0.2730292887828770329701595715303170 0.2657263599045893296731419294524377 0.1461853247179238943858531477474959 0.2472282818117836636295972426507768 0.06783074478282607934116386237659115 || 0.99999999999999999999991575375761855
0.2730292887828770329701595715303174 0.2657263599045893296731419294524381 0.1461853247179238943858531477474961 0.2472282818117836636295972426507773 0.06783074478282607934116386237659124 || 0.99999999999999999999991575375762014
Время: 3
Тест: 60
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718818 0.2657263599045893289396052100083676 0.1461853247179238939823090523745172 0.2472282818117836629471244053337525 0.06783074478282607915391732039518012 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968369922
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
Время: 4
Тест: 75
0.2730292887828523350918462646873233 0.2657263599045652924083824678106863 0.1461853247179106706493918712130509 0.2472282818117612996771912020956888 0.06783074478281994345922967379801888 || 0.99999999999990954128604147960476818
0.2730292887828523350918462646873233 0.2657263599045652924083824678106863 0.1461853247179106706493918712130509 0.2472282818117612996771912020956888 0.06783074478281994345922967379801888 || 0.99999999999990954128604147960476818
0.2730292887828523350918462646873233 0.2657263599045652924083824678106863 0.1461853247179106706493918712130509 0.2472282818117612996771912020956888 0.06783074478281994345922967379801888 || 0.99999999999990954128604147960476818
0.2730292887828523350918462646873230 0.2657263599045652924083824678106859 0.1461853247179106706493918712130506 0.2472282818117612996771912020956884 0.06783074478281994345922967379801876 || 0.99999999999990954128604147960476666
0.2730292887828523350918462646873233 0.2657263599045652924083824678106863 0.1461853247179106706493918712130509 0.2472282818117612996771912020956888 0.06783074478281994345922967379801888 || 0.99999999999990954128604147960476818
Время: 3
Тест: 90
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258548 0.2657263591169362384688919123320136 0.1461853242846084982613861358960977 0.2472282810789616715920519228547582 0.06783074458176550023240385632850703 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723133
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
Время: 4
Тест: 105
0.2730027709257946293603202738638419 0.2657005513414626796360668667984636 0.1461711265285439358765844877235809 0.2472042698668636201696887313196760 0.06782415674971079554627065634472917 || 0.99990287541237566058893101605029157
0.2730027709257946293603202738638419 0.2657005513414626796360668667984636 0.1461711265285439358765844877235809 0.2472042698668636201696887313196760 0.06782415674971079554627065634472917 || 0.99990287541237566058893101605029157
0.2730027709257946293603202738638419 0.2657005513414626796360668667984636 0.1461711265285439358765844877235809 0.2472042698668636201696887313196760 0.06782415674971079554627065634472917 || 0.99990287541237566058893101605029157
0.2730027709257946293603202738638413 0.2657005513414626796360668667984631 0.1461711265285439358765844877235806 0.2472042698668636201696887313196756 0.06782415674971079554627065634472905 || 0.99990287541237566058893101605028965
0.2730027709257946293603202738638419 0.2657005513414626796360668667984636 0.1461711265285439358765844877235809 0.2472042698668636201696887313196760 0.06782415674971079554627065634472917 || 0.99990287541237566058893101605029157
Время: 3
Тест: 120
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070982 0.01102024467759399595775450897719917 0.006062620386037311053865263230157291 0.01025308952324214872533623929149360 0.002813087133841649504461690768456168 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016049
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
Время: 3
Тест: 135
1.214611175281497520611594859682106E-45294 1.182123015980360633415277528532776E-45294 6.503270394765076933901585145703277E-45295 1.099831579508799616945484728203976E-45294 3.017551011034777788795921099547789E-45295 || 4.4486479113506432432421077409439646E-45294
1.214611175281497520611594859682106E-45294 1.182123015980360633415277528532776E-45294 6.503270394765076933901585145703277E-45295 1.099831579508799616945484728203976E-45294 3.017551011034777788795921099547789E-45295 || 4.4486479113506432432421077409439646E-45294
1.214611175281497520611594859682106E-45294 1.182123015980360633415277528532776E-45294 6.503270394765076933901585145703277E-45295 1.099831579508799616945484728203976E-45294 3.017551011034777788795921099547789E-45295 || 4.4486479113506432432421077409439646E-45294
1.214611175281497520611594859682104E-45294 1.182123015980360633415277528532773E-45294 6.503270394765076933901585145703268E-45295 1.099831579508799616945484728203975E-45294 3.017551011034777788795921099547784E-45295 || 4.4486479113506432432421077409439572E-45294
1.214611175281497520611594859682106E-45294 1.182123015980360633415277528532776E-45294 6.503270394765076933901585145703277E-45295 1.099831579508799616945484728203976E-45294 3.017551011034777788795921099547789E-45295 || 4.4486479113506432432421077409439646E-45294
Время: 3
Тест: 150
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199849E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380794E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325263E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190750E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494657E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461217E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
Время: 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понял, вы вычисляете стационарное распределение для *однородной цепи Маркова* путем возведения матрицы в степень `2^80`. Степень очень велика. Любую ошибку округления такая степень увеличит до такой степени, что вычисления потеряют всякий смысл.

Ошибки нужно контролировать. В вашем случае лучше всего нормировать строки матрицы после умножения.

```java
...
// вызывать каждый раз после умножения
p = matrixNormalization(5, 5, p);
...
```

```java
public static double[][] matrixNormalization(
        int m, int n, double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[m][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double v : a[i])
            sum += v;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            b[i][j] = a[i][j] / sum;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Матрица сойдется к ответу, несмотря на ошибки округления:

> ```
> 0.2730    0.2657    0.1462    0.2472    0.0678
> 0.2730    0.2657    0.1462    0.2472    0.0678
> 0.2730    0.2657    0.1462    0.2472    0.0678
> 0.2730    0.2657    0.1462    0.2472    0.0678
> 0.2730    0.2657    0.1462    0.2472    0.0678
> ```